# Mejor método de análisis de datos

Tags: c#

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde tengo que tomar una serie de datos generados por sensores (A y B, para detección de presencia) en intervalos de 1 segundo aproximadamente y determinar si el objeto realiza una transición de A -> B o de B -> A

Por lo tanto, tendré una entrada de datos similar a esta:

```
Caso 1           Caso 2        Caso 3
A | B            A | B         A | B
0 | 1            1 | 1         1 | 0
0 | 1            0 | 1         0 | 1
1 | 1            0 | 0         0 | 0
1 | 0            0 | 0         0 | 0
1 | 1            0 | 0         0 | 0
1 | 0            0 | 0         0 | 0
1 | 0            0 | 0         0 | 0
0 | 0            0 | 0         0 | 0
0 | 0            0 | 0         0 | 0
```

Donde 1 es objeto detectado y 0, el caso contrario. El caso 1 y 3 muestran claramente el tipo de transición realizada por el objeto. Pero en algunas ocasiones, este es detectado por ambos sensores a la vez en la primera “ronda” (por ignorancia de un término más acorde) ¿Existe algún método, algoritmo o tip para analizar esta serie de datos? He intentado algunos, pero son soluciones a casos particulares, y quisiera agrupar en un solo algoritmo la mayor cantidad de variantes posibles.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

**Actualización**

Es un sistema de control de personal por medio de RFID, en lugares cerrados, túneles, donde siempre entran en vehículos a menos que estén realizando trabajos en esa zona y entren a pie. Existen antenas separadas por 30 metros que van leyendo todos los ID que tengan en su rango de cobertura.

Luego envían esos datos por TCP hasta un servidor donde corre un software encargado de procesar todos los ID y determinar si están entrando o saliendo del túnel. Esto con el fin de saber en tiempo real cuantas personas están dentro (útil en casos de emergencias)

Actualmente, cada vez que un ID es leído por una antena se ejecuta el siguiente código donde `dir` indica si la antena que lo leyó fue la A o la B, y `_threshold` indica la cantidad de veces que debe ser leída por la ultima antena para considerar un evento de entrada o salida como finalizado:

```
if (dir == Reader.DirectionEnum.Out)
{
    //OUT
    _port1DateTime = DateTime.Now; //Instante de tiempo en el lo detecta el reader OUT (cualquiera)
    if (_port0Read && Math.Abs((_port0DateTime - _port1DateTime).TotalSeconds) < 1.5)
        return; //Si no han pasado mas de 1 segundo se asumen que el tag esta siendo leido por ambos readers, y se ignora

    _port1Read = true; //Bandera indicando que ya lo leyo el (los) reader(s) OUT
    if (_port0Read)
    {
        //Si ya lo leyo el reader IN (cualquiera) se asume transicion A -> B
        if (_transition == TransitionEnum.BtoA)
        {
            //Si ya se determino una transicion B -> A (entro y salio de la zona)
            //Se resetea la transicion
            _transition = TransitionEnum.None;
            _counterThreshold = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //Se asigna la transicion A -> B
            _transition = TransitionEnum.AtoB;
        }
        //Se resetea la bandera que indica que lo leyo el reader IN (cualquiera)
        _port1Read = false;
        _port0Read = false;
    }
    if (_transition == TransitionEnum.AtoB)
    {
        //Si no tenia transicion asignada (trans == none)
        //Se incrementa el contador de umbral mientras sea leido por el reader OUT (cualquiera)
        _counterThreshold++;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Tag] " + "OUT - " + this.ToString() + " - Counter:" + _counterThreshold);
         if (_counterThreshold >= _threshold)
         {
             //Si ya se supero el umbral de lecturas se asume que finalizo la transicion
             //Se reporta a la base de datos dicha transicion
             _accessDateTime = _port1DateTime;
             _dir = Reader.DirectionEnum.Out;
             StoreDatabase(this, null); //taccess = dt_b
             _transition = TransitionEnum.None;
             _counterThreshold = 0;
         }
     }
 }
 else
 {
     //IN
     _port0DateTime = DateTime.Now;
     if (_port1Read && Math.Abs((_port0DateTime - _port1DateTime).TotalSeconds) < 1)
         return; //Si no han pasado mas de 1 segundo se asumen que el tag esta siendo leido por ambos readers, y se ignora
     _port0Read = true;
     if (_port1Read)
     {
         if (_transition == TransitionEnum.AtoB)
         {
             _transition = TransitionEnum.None;
             _counterThreshold = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             _transition = TransitionEnum.BtoA;
         }
         _port1Read = false;
         _port0Read = false;
     }
     if (_transition == TransitionEnum.BtoA)
     {
         _counterThreshold++;
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Tag] " + "IN - " + this.ToString() + " - Counter:" + _counterThreshold);
         if (_counterThreshold >= _threshold)
         {
             _accessDateTime = _port0DateTime;
             _dir = Reader.DirectionEnum.In;
             StoreDatabase(this, null); //taccess = dt_a
             _transition = TransitionEnum.None;
             _counterThreshold = 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Quieres obtener (contar) aquellos registros donde el dato fue detectado por ambos sensores?

Comment: Como tienes organizados los datos, en arreglos? Listas de objetos? Que informacion necesitas? Puedes incluir algo de codigo y ser mas especifico?

Comment: También ayudaría que menciones un poco de qué se trata para agregar algo de contexto ¿Son detectores como los de una alarma hogareña? ¿se encuentran en habitaciones diferentes? ¿cuál es el objetivo de detectar transiciones? ¿diferenciar si es más de una persona?

Comment: @Tuco  Se agrego mas información y se actualizo la pregunta.

Comment: El caso parece un poco complejo pero..y si eliminas todas las lecturas en las que la tarjeta es detectada por ambas antenas? Haciendolo asi, yo creo que consigues perfectamente detectar el tránsito.

Comment: Pensándolo mejor, en lugar de almacenar 1 o 0,en caso de que sean las dos antenas las que tienen lectura, podrías asignar 0.5 a cada una, y para comprobar la dirección, por ejemplo en el caso 2, cuando tienes la segunda lectura, puedes comprobar cual es la anterior lectura >0 en el lector contrario. Así tendrias la dirección del movimiento